# Scala: Can I write my function like a method of type?

Tags: scala

Is it possible to write postfix function that I can use like that:

```
//...

val myStr: String = "some string"

val myNewStr = myStr myFunction otherMyFunction // Instead of: otherMyFunction(myFunction(myStr))

def myFunction(String: str): String {
//do something
}

def otherMyFunction(String: str): String {
//do something
}

//...
```

I want to call my function like if it's a method of type String. It there such possibility? If there is, what syntax I have to use?

Comment: You seem to be looking for "extension classes" (aka "implicit classes" in Scala 2) in combination with postfix

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds like what you're asking is whether you can add a method to the String type. Yes, you can do that with an implicit class. See, for example, https://www.baeldung.com/scala/implicit-classes.

Answer (score 1):

In Scala 2 and without Scalaz or other non-core functional lib:

```
(myFunction compose otherMyFunction) (myStr)
```

Scala 2.13 you can use the pipe [chaining operator](https://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/api/2.13.x/scala/util/ChainingOps.html#pipe%5BB%5D(f:A=%3EB):B)